# set capstyle of spines for pdf backend

Tags: python, matplotlib

Figures rendered with the PDF backend have a 'butt' capstyle in my reader. (If I zoom at the corner of a figure in a pdf, I do not see a square corner, but the overlap of shortened lines.) I would like either a 'round' or 'projecting' (what matplotlib calls the 'square' capstyle) cap. Thus the `Spine` objects are in question, and a `Spine` is a `Patch` is an `Artist`, none of which seem to have anything like the `set_solid_capstyle()` of `Line2D`, so I'm not sure how or where to force a particular capstyle, or if it's even possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. I did a little bit of the backend's work in my main script, setting up a `RendererPdf` (defined in `backend_pdf.py`) and conatining a `GraphicsContextPdf` which is a `GraphicsContextBase` which keeps a capstyle, intialized as `butt`. As confirmed by `grep`, this is the only place where `butt` is hardcoded as a capstyle. After some ipython debugging, I've found that a new `GraphicsContextPdf` or 'gc' is generated each time a patch is drawn (c.f. `patches.py:392`, called by way of a necessary `fig.draw()` in the main script), and the settings for the new gc (again initialized as `butt`) are incorporated into the original `RendererPdf`'s gc. So everything gets a `butt` capstyle. `Line2D` objects are not patches, so they can maintain a particular capstyle.